# Taking a Word document out of design mode

Tags: ms-word, cpu-word

This should be a really simple thing that for some reason I can get to work.

I have an MS Word document which has a drop-down field.  If I double-click it - a dialog comes up to add or remove things from the drop-down field.

I just need to be able to get out of this mode so that the drop-down field behaves like it should from a user's point-of-view rather than from a design point-of-view.  Basically I just need it to display the items rather than a dialog to allow me to add and remove the items.

According to what I've read, it looks like I should be able to do this by going to Developer, and then toggling the Design Mode button.  This doesn't work; whether the Design Mode button is on or off I still can't get it to just act like a drop-down.

Thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're using a legacy form field dropdown. For those to operate as a dropdown, you must protect the document for forms:

1. On the Developer tab, click on **Restrict Editing**. The Restrict Editing task pane opens.
2. In the task pane, check the box beside **Allow only this type of editing in the document**.
3. In the next dropdown, choose **Filling in forms**.
4. Click on **Yes, Start Enforcing Protection**.

Protected forms don't allow text to be edited in protected sections. In those areas, only form fields allow you to enter text. If that's too restrictive, look into *Content Controls*, which don't require document protection.